# PyTorch not detecting AMD GPU although ROCM installed on Ubuntu 20.04 LST

Tags: ubuntu, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, amd-rocm

- OS Version: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- PyTorch Version: 2.0
- ROCm version: 5.0.2

I installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my desktop with AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT GPU.  Both ROCM and PyTorch installed fine. However, PyTorch is not able to detect GPU.   Any pointers here?

```
$ python -c "import torch; print(torch.__version__)"
2.0.0+cu117
```

```
$ apt show rocm-libs -a

Package: rocm-libs

Version: 5.0.2.50002-72

Priority: optional

Section: devel

Maintainer: ROCm Libs Support <rocm-libs.support@amd.com>

Installed-Size: 13.3 kB

Depends: hipblas, hipfft, hipsolver, hipsparse, miopen-hip, rccl, rocalution, rocblas, rocfft, rocrand, rocsolver, rocsparse, rocm-core, hipblas-dev, hipcub-dev, hipfft-dev, hipsolver-dev, hipsparse-dev, miopen-hip-dev, rccl-dev, rocalution-dev, rocblas-dev, rocfft-dev, rocprim-dev, rocrand-dev, rocsolver-dev, rocsparse-dev, rocthrust-dev

Homepage: https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm

Download-Size: 898 B

APT-Sources: https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/5.0.2 ubuntu/main amd64 Packages

Description: Radeon Open Compute (ROCm) Runtime software stack
```

```
$ rocminfo | grep 'Name:'
  Name:                    Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-10100 CPU @ 3.60GHz
  Marketing Name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-10100 CPU @ 3.60GHz
  Vendor Name:             CPU                                
  Name:                    gfx1010                            
  Marketing Name:          AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT              
  Vendor Name:             AMD                                
      Name:                    amdgcn-amd-amdhsa--gfx1010:xnack-
```

```
$ python3

Python 3.9.16 (main, Mar 8 2023, 14:00:05)

[GCC 11.2.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import torch

>>> print("GPU available:", torch.cuda.is_available())

GPU available: False
```

I have also tried Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. But it does not work either.

Comment: What exactly did you do to install pytorch? Did you use the pip3/conda command on the Getting Started page of PyTorch's website?

Comment: Initially, I used the command to install PyTorch: `pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/rocm5.4.2 `   But it did not work (not recognizing GPU). Then I uninstalled Pytorch, and reinstalled using the command:  `pip install torch torchvision -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/rocm4.0/torch_rocm.html`

Comment: Try with the nightly: `pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/rocm5.4.2` Are you also using anaconda?

Comment: I tried the nightly using the command above. Pytorch installation is fine.  But it still does not recognize GPU. Yes, I am using MiniConda

Comment: In terminal, try: `export HSA_OVERRIDE_GFX_VERSION=10.3.0` or start the python shell with 'HSA_OVERRIDE_GFX_VERSION=10.3.0 python3` and see if 'cuda' calls work

Comment: Nope. Tried both. PyTorch  is still not able to detect GPU.   AMD GPU seems to be much more challenging than NVIDIA GPU to set up.

Comment: It's leagues more difficult and still not at the same level of performance. That's a big reason Nvidia is recommended over AMD. It may be a driver issue possibly. Are you on the latest? If so, maybe try with an older version.

Comment: You may need to use DirectML. It looks like Navi cards aren't supported by DL libraries without a lot of tinkering. https://github.com/microsoft/DirectML. After cloning the report, you'd run `pip3 install torch-directml` then you can test with `import torch; import torch_directml; device = torch_directml.device("cuda")` (you may not need the `"cuda"` parameter.

Comment: When  you talk about trying an older version,  do you mean an older version of ROCM?  I have ROCM 5.0.2 installed.  Which version do you suggest? Or will it be helpful to try an older PyTorch version?

Comment: ROCM probably does not support  Radeon RX 5700 XT, per this talk from AMD: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPrfh7MNV_0  .  I give up for now. Unless there is new development from AMD

Comment: That's why I linked to DirectML. After reading, it seems like Navi (RX 5000 series) doesn't have much support. People have gotten 5799xt to work with DirectML though.

Comment: I followed the instructions.  But 'import torch_directml' errors out:  OSError: libd3d12.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: You're most likely missing a path in your .bashrc file. If the lib3d12.so file exists but the directory path isn't in set in .bashrc, you can find it with this terminal command `locate lib3d12.so`. If it finds it, note the directory path and use this command: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH={path_to_file}:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` without the `{ }`, then enter either of these commands: `source ~/.bashrc` or `. ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

> 2.0.0+cu117

**cu117** means than you install version for **NVidia CUDA 11.7** while you need a build for **ROCm**

Pytorch since version 1.8 available for ROCm from official site (but you need to pay attention to version of ROCm (current is 5.4.2) and version of you GPU(gfx1010))
https://pytorch.org/blog/pytorch-for-amd-rocm-platform-now-available-as-python-package/

AMD doc page for ROCm 5.x can be also helpful if you decide other options like build from sources
https://docs.amd.com/bundle/ROCm-Deep-Learning-Guide-v5.0/page/Deep_Learning_Frameworks.html